# DiscordJS Error POST-FAILED Code: 50001 remove error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

im owning a Discord bot for music and stuff.
My console always gets spammed full with this message:

```
20:2:2022 - 17:22 | Info: [Slash Command]: [POST-FAILED] Guild 945348402374385736, Command: youtube
DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/m9mo/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/m9mo/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async /home/m9mo/util/RegisterSlashCommands.js:36:9 {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/applications/895283932252241940/guilds/945348402374385736/commands',
  code: 50001,
  httpStatus: 403
}
```

I know the reason for this error but some people are creating their own invite link using the id of the bot...
Is there any way to disable this message?

Comment: Show some code where this error coming from

Answer (score 0):

You could try finding the error code (In this case `50001`) of that specific error, then when you receive an error, stop it from being logged. You can find all the relevant error codes here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes#json-json-error-codes

You might also want to consider sending some kind of message like `I'm missing permission to do...`